# IWizard with multiproject template to grab nuget prerelease package

Tags: c#, nuget, signalr, project-template

I have created a multi-project template and when creating a new project I'm having success installing nuget packages into all my projects when it comes to regular release versions, but I'm trying to grab signalr's **prerelease** version and it can't find the version '1.0.0-alpha2'. I assume because its a prelease. Although I can grab it from within VS's PM prompt using :

```
Install-Package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS -version 1.0.0-alpha2
```

...Is there something different with the API that I need to do to grab it or what am I doing wrong?

Example within my project templates wizard

```
 var componentModel = (IComponentModel)services.GetService(typeof(SComponentModel));
 IVsPackageInstaller installerServices = componentModel.GetService<IVsPackageInstaller();

 installerServices.InstallPackage("http://packages.nuget.org", project, "Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.JS", "1.0.0-alpha2", false);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okay this works with https://www.nuget.org/api/v2/ as the target, not the older v1 at packages.nuget.org. Found out v2 with fiddler

Comment: I was trying the same, but i got an error stating  "An exception of type 'System.InvalidOperationException' occurred in NuGet.VisualStudio.dll but was not handled in user code

Additional information: The project 'Core' is unsupported". Do you have any idea why i am getting this error ?

Comment: What version is your Nuget.VisualStudio.dll ?   Did you follow this? http://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/invoking-nuget-services-from-inside-visual-studio       If you're using the new version, you don't reference Nuget.Core.dll anymore

Comment: yes, i removed the nuget.core and it worked. Thanks :)